# Restrict access to database resources in Entity Framework + UoW + Generic Repositories

Tags: entity-framework, unit-of-work, repository

I'm using ASP.NET MVC3 with Entity Framework 4.

I am using the Unit Of Work + Generic Repository pattern.

I searched for similar question everywhere, I see that many people have my problem, but still can't find a good and practical solution.

We have a multi-tenant database.

Imagine a database with a similar structure:

- customers
- groups, associated to a customer
- users, associated to one or many groups

And then, for each customer we have

- resources, associated to one or many groups, and linked between each other with foreign keys, many-to-many relationships and so on

So, when a user logs in, he is associated to one or many groups, and he needs to have access to the parent and child resources associated to that groups.

Now the problem is:

I implemented a sort of pre-filtering with a .Where() clause into the unit of work, in the repositories, based on the id of the logged in user.

And this is working.

The pre-filtering I did on the repositories is working fine, but of course it works only if you access directly the repository of the sources of TYPE A or TYPE B or TYPE C and so on.

But a resource is linked to other resources with many-to-many tables and foreign keys.

So, it happens that sometimes a resource belongs to a group to which the user has access, but sometimes the resources linked to this resource belong to a group to which the user does not have access.

If I traverse the navigation properties of the "parent" resource, the user can access all the linked resources, even the one belonging to other groups.

So, if you are starting from a TYPE A resource, and traverse the navigation properties to reach the TYPE B and TYPE C resources, they are not filtered.

If you access the TYPE B and TYPE C repositories, they are filtered.

Now my filters, as I said before, are in the Unit Of Work class, but I tried to move them into a custom DBContext, applying the filters directly into the DBSet, but nothing changes:

It seems that EF is accessing directly the database to build the navigation properties, thus not using the other repositories or the other DBSet, avoiding the prefilter.

What can we do?

I see that NHibernate has Global Filters that could accomplish my task, so I'm evaluating a migration from EF to NH.

I see that many other people is asking for .Include() filters, thus disabling lazy loading.

Thank you.

I can provide some piece of code if needed, but I hope I explained my problem correctly.

Thank you i.a.

Best Regards,

Marco

Answer (score 0):

I saw a solution with mapping to views and stored procedures, but I'm not sure how hard it was in development and maintanace. In short, it is possible to map EF model to views, where data will be filtered; in this solution each user have own database credentials.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Oleg.  
I understand your solution, but I fear that it will be a pain to maintain, so I will wait for other proposals.  
Btw, thank you.  
Anybody knows if EF 5 or EF 6 will implement some kind of .Include(<filters>, or perhaps Global Filters?  
Anybody with experiance with NHibernate can tell me if I can accomplish this task with global filters?

Comment: Anybody has other solutions? I'm afraid i think i will have to migrate to NHiberanate.

Comment: FYI, i opened an issue con Codeplex, and the Entity Framework team said that they will evaluate the scenario for future releases.

http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/945

Comment: Fine, but this feature is one of top-10 requests at uservoice.com in at least the latest two years, so chances are not very good.